# Django forms.MultipleChoiceField with CheckboxSelectMultiple and Bootstrap custom-control-input is reset when form.is_bound

Tags: html, django, forms, bootstrap-4

I have a form field:

Forms.py

```
colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices= [(1,'blue'),(2,'red'),(3,'green')]
    )
```

I can easily render this field like this:

Template.html

```
{{ form.colors }}
```

And get something that looks like this:

[image]

So the html code looks like that:

```
<ul id="id_colors">
    <li><label for="id_colors_0"><input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="1" id="id_colors_0" checked="">
 blue</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_colors_1"><input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="2" id="id_colors_1" checked="">
 red</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_colors_2"><input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="3" id="id_colors_2">
 green</label>

</li>
</ul>
```

This is really simple ! And it's working fine.

Now, let's say I want to render this differently, exactly like this:

[image]

With bootstrap custom-control-input.

Bootstrap documentation show this code to achieve this:

```
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" name="example1">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Check this custom checkbox</label>
  </div>
```

So, in my template I did something like that:

Template.html

```
<div class="custom-checkbox">
    <ul id="id_colors"> 
        {% for key, value in colors %}
            <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="{{key}}" name="colors" id="id_colors_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_colors_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">{{value}}</label>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

(Where "colors" is just my list that I pass to the template thru the view)

With that template, the field looks exactly like I want.
When rendered, the html looks like this:

```
<ul id="id_colors">              
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="1" name="colors" id="id_colors_0">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_colors_0">blue</label>
        </li>
    
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="2" name="colors" id="id_colors_1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_colors_1">red</label>
        </li>
    
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="3" name="colors" id="id_colors_2">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_colors_2">green</label>
        </li>
    
</ul>
```

So everything is working fine !

Yes, except that, if I submit the form, and it is not validated (form.is_bound), the checked checkbox are going to be reset.

If I do not apply the custom-control-input style, and render this field in a simple way, I do not have this problem...

If you guys have any idea how to fix that.

Comment: Can you share the view wher you process the form?

Comment: Nothing special in the view right now, just rendering the form with the colors choices in context

Answer (score 0):

I ended by created a style to match the bootstrap custom form style, so in my template, I can keep think simple, and just call the field:

template.html

```
{% render_field form.colors class="My-CheckBoxStyle"%}
```

Like this, everything is working fine !